# Animate iframe content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-animate

Im dynamically setting the contents of an iFrame in a web app. Yes, using an iFrame is unfortunately needed:) No cross-domain content is used

Im able to set the content, find elements inside the iframe etc. But now I would like to animate some elements inside the iframe. In the app I don't get any error messages, fadeIn(1000), fadeOut(1000) and animate just doesn't do anything at all. The architecture of the app would be to complicated to recreate in a fiddle but Im doing the following.

Adding the iframe to the site, waiting for the iframe to load, accessing the contents and appending jquery to the head of the iframe with:

`head.append($('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-     requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="/assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>'))`

<strike>Here is a small fiddle where I tried to break it down, but jsfiddle wouldn't let me write html in the JS window so I couldn't get the append part to work.</strike>

https://jsfiddle.net/MacG/Lnwx8seg/7/

Is it even possible to use jquery metods and animations on elements in an iframe?.

**EDIT:**

I've manage to animate elements in a simple jsfiddle following @P. Frank answer. However trying to animate an element in a more complex iframe environment fails as seen in this updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MacG/5ryLdnLz/1/

(Well, I guess it kind of works, but way to slow and choppy so it doesn't look much like an animation at all. Sometimes the element just disappear at the end of the animation, without any fading at all.

Any Idea on how I can get a smooth animation working in an iframe environment like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. work fine

https://jsfiddle.net/95b6ezkv/

```
$(header).animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

Comment: Thanks this does work, however I still have problems in my use case. I updated the question

Comment: Turns out my iframe architecture was to deep, works great after a bit of optimization:)